# Why did Ed Sheeran say this in his song?

Tags: grammar

I'm listening to this [song](https://youtu.be/OmketaeA0m0?t=285) for Ed Sheeran and he said the following:

> I don't deserved it

Is that a grammatical error or he did that for a purpose? The subtitle, however, tells that he said

> I don't deserve this

But I listened to it many times and I'm quite sure that he said what I heard at the beginning.

Comment: The YouTube video linked in your question is not sung by Ed Sheeran. This is the original recording https://youtu.be/UDDMYw_IZnE?t=3m09s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words in your excerpt seem to be

> **I don't deserve this**

since it is a refrain of the previous lyrics at [3:47](https://youtu.be/OmketaeA0m0?t=228).

The captioning says "***this***" and Sheeran seems to pronounce it as "***thit***" *(not a misspelling)*.

Comment: So, why would he say this?

Comment: **One interpretation might be**: It's a song about *once lost love*, and obviously something went horribly wrong, but another chance has presented itself and the singer, being *humble*, is saying he doesn't deserve the second chance.

Comment: I meant why did he say "thit"/

Comment: Probably just his accent.

Comment: @Peter I don't think it makes sense that it's just his accent. As you mention, it is a refrain of the previous lyric, where he pronounces it "I don't deserve this"; the second time, it is different. If it were his accent, they would sound the same, but they don't. It sounds to me like he stumbled while recording this last line and they kept it.